# How do I build a hello world class with maven?

Tags: java, maven-2

Now the source code is ready, how can I build it with maven?

Suppose the source file is `hw.java`

I've googled some time, all the solutions requires me to set the directory in a fixed manner.

But what I want to do is keep `hw.java` in current directory (`.`), and then:

```
vi pom.xml
...
mkdir build
cd build
maven ...
```

Can I have that kind of freedom with maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose the source file is `hw.java`

Bad choice for a class file name in Java :)

> I've googled some time,all the solutions requires me to set the directory in fixed manner.

Not really fixed but "warmly suggested" (Maven relies on conventions - the [directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) being one of them - and it is highly recommended to follow Maven's conventions if you decide to use it, less work, less troubles).

> But what I want to do is keep hw.java in current directory (.) (...)

I think you'll need at least a directory below the `pom.xml` to store java sources.

> Can I have that kind of freedom with maven?

Maven is flexible and defaults **are** configurable but you should really use the conventions (or another tool than Maven). I suggest to create your project using the archetype for a simple project:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=com.stackoverflow \
                          -DartifactId=Q2841166 \
                          -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Then put your sources under `src/main/java` (in the appropriate package) and run `mvn install`.

---

**Update:** It looks like you don't understand what I'm saying or you just don't want to listen. In that case, feel free to modify the `build` element as **documented** in [the POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Element) (as I said, defaults **ARE NOT MANDATORY**):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

Now, because changing these defaults is not recommended, because Maven doesn't encourage doing this, because it's a bad idea if you're not dealing with a legacy project, because it's useless work if you don't have to, because this will cause more troubles than benefits, don't expect to find a "tutorial" about this. Let me rephrase it: what you're asking for is a **"how to shoot myself in the foot"** tutorial and that's just ridiculous.

Last thing: if Maven doesn't work the way you want it to work, don't use Maven, that's the best advice I can give you.

Comment: @httpinterpret Nothing is mandatory, defaults **can** be changed. But I do not recommend to go this way.

Comment: There is no tutorial on how one **can** change the defaults at all.

Comment: This is because the Maven community strongly discourages changing said defaults, @httpinterpret.

Comment: Then they should document it as **mandatory**,not **defaults**.

Comment: @httpinterpret No they should **not** and the way to change **is** documented. There is just no tutorial about the wrong way to do things (I wonder why...).

Answer (score 1):

[Google it!](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rls=en&q=maven+hello+world)

http://cvs.peopleware.be/training/maven/maven2/helloWorld.html

http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

etc...

Comment: @Downvoter Thank you very much! Especially for your reasoning.

Comment: @zaf sometimes it's frustrating (+1)

Comment: @httpinternet you have edited your question. Heavily. Next time give a thought before asking a question. It saves everyone time.

Comment: @zaf,sure,sorry for late clarification!